# How to slow down a sine wave?

Tags: unity-game-engine, trigonometry

I want to program a *bouncing* ball. The actual bounce shouldn't follow real physic laws but rather build an absolute sine wave. Like in this image

[image]

That is pretty easy so far. See the attached code.

However I want to slow down the movement of my ball as soon as I press a button.

I'll reduce the movement speed which will slow down the transformation on the x axis. But the ball is still bouncing pretty fast up and down, because neither frequency nor magnitude of the sine wave has changed. But when I change one or both, this will end in a weird behavior.

Imagine the ball is on the downmove at 20% of the distance from top to bottom. When I now change any sine parameters the ball will instantly move on the y axis which looks really weird and not smooth.

So my actual question is: **How can I slow down an absolute sine wave (x/y axis translation) without choppy movement?**

```
float _movementSpeed = 10.0f;
float _sineFrequency = 5.0f;
float _sineMagnitude = 2.5f;

Vector3 _axis;
Vector3 _direction;
Vector3 _position;

void Awake()
{
    _position = transform.position;
    _axis = transform.up;
    _direction = transform.right;
}

void Update()
{
    _position += _direction * Time.deltaTime * _movementSpeed;
    // Time.time is the time since the start of the game
    transform.position = _position + _axis * Mathf.Abs(Mathf.Sin(Time.time * _sineFrequency)) * _sineMagnitude;
}
```

Comment: Isn't the speed in the y direction entirely dependent on the speed in the x direction?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want this (more red - lower freq, more blue - higher):

[image: A graph of a sine wave in time with changing frequency]
The easiest way to achieve this is to scale deltatime, for example this was generated with:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Bounce : MonoBehaviour {

    // for visualisation of results
    public Graph graph;

    [Range(0, 10)]
    public float frequency = 1;

    float t;

    void Update()
    {
        t += Time.deltaTime * frequency;

        float y = Mathf.Abs(Mathf.Sin(t));
        float time = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;

        graph.AddPoint(time, y, Color.Lerp(Color.red, Color.blue, frequency/10));
    }

}
```

And for the completeness, the `Graph` class:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Graph : MonoBehaviour {

    struct PosAndColor
    {
        public Vector3 pos;
        public Color color;
    }


    List<PosAndColor> values=new List<PosAndColor>();


    public void AddPoint(float x, float y, Color c)
    {
        values.Add(new PosAndColor() { pos = new Vector3(x, y, 0), color = c });
    }


    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < values.Count; i++)
        {
            Gizmos.color = values[i - 1].color;
            Gizmos.DrawLine(values[i - 1].pos, values[i].pos);
        }
    }

}
```

---

Another aproach would be to change the frequency with the offset of your sine to match the current amplitude. I don't think you'd need this here, but if you want to I can post some more on the subject.